# Python - Firestore AND condition

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore

I am following documentation on Google Firestore, but it gives me errors. I am new to this.

I am trying to select a load of data happening yesterday only - so between unix start date and unix end date.
Error happens with variable doc_all.

I noticed that one issue is the field formats, Firestore 'created' is a datetime, so I went to convert my start and end to that, but that also shows me all records and not records from yesterday

> UserWarning: Detected filter using positional arguments. Prefer using the 'filter' keyword argument instead.
> return query.where(field_path, op_string, value)

```
today = datetime.utcnow().date() - timedelta(1)
start0 = int(datetime(today.year, today.month, today.day, tzinfo=tz.tzutc()).timestamp()) * 1000 # milliseconds
start = datetime.fromtimestamp(start0 / 1000)
end0 = start0 + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
end = start + timedelta(milliseconds=24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)

# docs_all = db.collection('collection).and(where('created', '>=', start).where('created', '<=', end)).stream() - this is my version of created between start and end
docs_all = db.collection('collection').where('created', '>=', 'start0').stream()


for doc in docs_all:
    print(doc.to_dict())
```

Comment: Your question should show the exact error message text so that we can see what you see is the problem here. Also you're not showing any variable called `doc_query` here. Please edit the question to add that by copy and pasting it, and explain what's not working the way you expect.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Doug asked for, and please also respond using @.

Comment: thanks @DougStevenson I have amended the question

Comment: This edit seems off: `where('created', '>=', 'start0')`. You're now comparing the `created` field to the string `'start0'`, and not to the calculated value of the `start0` variable. I strongly recommend actually reproducing the problem in a minimal amount of code, and to then copy/paste the code verbatim into your question.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thanks for that, I mentioned earlier that I am new to this. I used Firestore documentation where the string compared to was in quotes. But when even when i changed 'start0' to start0, I am not getting the filter applied and the function prints the all results, and also I dont know how I can make the where clause a 'between'

Comment: To query between two values, you can simply add to conditions: one for the `>=` and one for the `<=`. --- Outside of that, consider passing a `datetime` rather than an `int`, so ensure you're not converting to different units.

Answer (score 0):

I understand the reason for your conversions since Unix timestamps are traditionally in seconds, but Firestore timestamps are in milliseconds

But do you think refactoring your code this way is same as what you tried to accomplish ?

```
# Get yesterday's start and end datetime
yesterday = datetime.utcnow().date() - timedelta(days=1)
start = datetime(yesterday.year, yesterday.month, yesterday.day)
end = start + timedelta(days=1)

# Query the Firestore database
docs_all = db.collection('your_collection').where('created', '>=', start).where('created', '<', end).stream()
```